# Google Analytics sends uncaught exceptions twice

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics

In order to include the stacktrace of uncaught exceptions into google analytics, I replaced the default ExceptionParser with a custom one.
Now I get Exceptions with their stackstrace + another report with the exception without stacktrace (the default one). What am I doing wrong?

```
public class AnalyticsHelper
{
    /**
    * This method is called in my Application#onCreate(..)
    **/
    public static void initAnalytics(Context c)
    {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(c);
        analytics.setAppOptOut(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_ANAYLTICS_OPT_OUT, false));

        // setting uncaught exception handler
        ExceptionReporter reporter = new ExceptionReporter(analytics.getInstance(c).newTracker(R.xml.tracker), Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), c);
        reporter.setExceptionParser(new ExceptionParser()
        {
            @Override
            public String getDescription(String p_thread, Throwable throwable)
            {
                StringWriter trace = new StringWriter();
                throwable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(trace));
                String stacktrace = trace.toString();

                String message = (throwable.getMessage() == null) ? "no message" : throwable.getMessage();
                return "Message: " + message
                        + ", Stacktrace: " + stacktrace;
            }
        });

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(reporter);
    }
}
```

tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">5</integer>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">XXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Google Analytics document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions#uncaught):

> To automatically send all uncaught exceptions in your app using EasyTracker, add this line to your analytics.xml file:
>
> `<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>`
>
> After sending an exception using automatic exception measurement, EasyTracker will pass the exception on to the Thread's default exception handler.

By setting the `ga_reportUncaughtExceptions` to `true`, the `tacker` will automatically send the exception, thus you got one extra report without stacktrace. Remove it and you will get one report only.

Comment: How can you confirm/verify this?

Comment: You mean the behavior of `ga_reportUncaughtExceptions`?  I have added a reference link of the document to the answer.

Comment: No, you said by removing "ga_reportUncaughtExceptions", it would only send the one exception instead of both of them.